# Why adding type union makes it assignable to AnyAction

Tags: typescript, redux

While writing redux code I've stumbled on the type behavior that I do not understand.

In the code below you can't assign `anyaction` to `iaction`. But for some reason assigning `anyaction` to `iaction2` is fine. I'm trying to apply "Assignment Compatibility" part of specification here, but can't explain this difference.

What is going on? Clearly there exist values of type `AnyAction` that are not assignable to `IAction2`

```
export interface ILoadUserBegin {
    type: "LOAD_USER_BEGIN";
}

export interface ILoadUserSuccess {
    type: "LOAD_USER_SUCCESS";
    response: number;
}

type IAction = ILoadUserSuccess;
type IAction2 = ILoadUserBegin | ILoadUserSuccess;

// these are redux types

interface Action {
  type: any;
}

interface AnyAction extends Action {
  [extraProps: string]: any;
}

// tests

let iaction: IAction = { type: "LOAD_USER_SUCCESS", response: 2 };
let iaction2: IAction2 = { type: "LOAD_USER_BEGIN" };
let anyaction: AnyAction = { type: "foo" };

// ERROR
// Type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to type 'ILoadUserSuccess'.
// Property 'response' is missing in type 'AnyAction'.
iaction = anyaction;  

// But this is OK!
iaction2 = anyaction;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all, `Action` is assignable to `ILoadUserBegin`

```
let iaction1: ILoadUserBegin = anyaction;  // ok
```

So it's no surprise that it's assignable to a union type which contains `ILoadUserBegin` as one of its members.

The next question is why variable of `Action` type is assignable to `ILoadUserBegin`?

Because `Action` has `type` property, declared to have `any` type.

`any` is a special type which is compatible with anything, it suppresses type checking, so `{type: any}` type is compatible with `{type: "LOAD_USER_BEGIN"}` type.

Comment: Thanks, `type: any` is indeed a culprit. If I replace it by `type: string`, then everything behaves as expected.